# Sorting a list in C# with Icomparer

Tags: c#, icomparer

I want to sort the items in a combobox on the object.Frequency. I did some research and then I made this class:

```
 public class CompareByFrequency : IComparer<GenderFrequency>
 {
    public int Compare(GenderFrequency x, GenderFrequency y)
    {
        return x.Frequency.CompareTo(y.Frequency);
    }

    public static void QSFreq(List<GenderFrequency> g)
    {
        g.Sort(new CompareByFrequency());
    }
}
```

Then, to put my objects in the combobox (unsorted) I use:

```
private void showGenderfreq()
{
    cboGenderFreqs.Items.Clear();
    foreach (GenderFrequency gf in GenderFrequency.GenderFrequencies(
             Bird.getBirdFromCSV(txtFile.Text)))
    {
        cboGenderFreqs.Items.Add(gf);
    }
}
```

But obviously I want that combobox to be sorted to Frequency.
Where it is now:

1. Accipiter(2)
2. Allauda (1)
3. Anas (6)
   ...

it Should be

1. Anas(6)
2. Accipiter(2)
3. Allauda(1)

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `Frequency.CompareTo`? What is the type of `Frequency`?

Comment: What does your GenderFrequency-class look like? Can't you just do `OrderBy()`?

Comment: it's `(x.Frequency).compareTo(y.Freequency)`
Frequency is an integer, calculated in the class GenderFrequencies, it's the amount of times a given gender appears in my CSV
Here, for instance it returns 6 on the gender Anas

Comment: What type is `cboGenderFreqs.Items` ? a `List` ?

Comment: Check if you can sort them by typping this: cboGenderFreqs.Items.Sort(new CompareByFrequency());

Comment: Yes, It returns the items from a List `GenderFrequency` I generated

Comment: Why have done a `static` method to sort a list ? as you can simply do `myList.Sort( new CompareByFrequency() )`

Answer (score 1):

Well, wouldn't it be easier to do

```
cboGenderFreqs.Items.Clear();
cboGenderFreqs.Items.AddRange(
   GenderFrequency.GenderFrequencies.OrderByDescending(gf => gf.Frequency)
   .ToArray());
```